# Re-Sorting ListView ItemsSource Programmatically After Adding Row

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting, datatable

I've been working with WPF (C#) for six months. I've tried every way I can find online with no luck. When I add a new row to the listView ItemsSource (DataTable), it gets added at the end as the last row. Problem is I need it to be at the top as the first row, so after adding it I want to programmatically re-sort it so the new row is at the top. I don't get any errors with the methods I've tried, it just doesn't work.

```
XAML:
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable, Mode=TwoWay, 
        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                               
    x:Name=MyListView" Height="291">                               
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="GridView1">
             <GridViewColumn x:Name="ColumnToSort" 
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=position}">
                 <!--<GridViewColumn.Header>
                      <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="position"/>
                      </GridViewColumn.Header>-->
             </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I get the itemsource collection (DataTable) and add a row:

```
DataView collection = (DataView)MyListView.ItemsSource;
DataRowView drv = collection.AddNew();
drv["position"] = 1;
```

Methods I've tried:

**Method #1: (position is the datatable column name, MyDataTable is a VM DP)**

```
DataView view = MyViewModel.MyDataTable.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "position ASC";
```

**Method #2 (tried sorting by the header tag prop and also the column name)**

```
string sortby = header.Tag.ToString();
Sort(SortBy, ListSortDirection.Ascending);

private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        ICollectionView dataView =  
             CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListView.ItemsSource);

        dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        SortDescription sd = new SortDescription(sortBy, direction);
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
        dataView.Refresh();            
    }
```

**Method #3:**

```
DataView view = new DataView(MyViewModel.MyDataTable);
view.Sort = "position ASC";
```

**Method #4:**

```
MyViewModel.MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "position ASC";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding to the DataTable, not the DataView.

XAML:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataView, Mode=TwoWay, 
        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                               
    x:Name=MyListView" Height="291">                               
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="GridView1">
             <GridViewColumn x:Name="ColumnToSort" 
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=position}">
                 <!--<GridViewColumn.Header>
                      <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="position"/>
                      </GridViewColumn.Header>-->
             </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In ViewModel

```
this.MyDataView = MyDataTable.DefaultView;
MyDataView.Sort = "position ASC";
```

When you add your new row to the DataTable, be sure to refresh MyDataView.

Comment: By default WPF will bind to the `DefaultView`, so I don't think this will make any difference than what the OP is already doing.

Comment: It's fixed. I left the itemsSource as the datatable, added row to the datatable (instead of the dataview), then did this as Mark suggested:

Comment: OK don't hit the enter key as a CR when you're typing a comment or it submits it :) It's fixed. Thank you Mark! I left the itemsSource as the datatable, added row to the datatable (instead of the dataview), then as Mark suggested I created a dataview and sorted it which worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` (and `DataGrid`) won't automatically re-sort when a property changes in the underlying collection.  Since you know the exact type that you're binding to, why not just create the row and set the properties before you actually add it to the collection:

```
var newRow = this.MyDataTable.NewRow();
newRow["Position"] = 1;
this.MyDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```